# Doctrine access unrelated entity / collection in another entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have unrelated models, `Things`, `Stuff`, `Cosas` and `PublicHolidays`. I also have a `DateTimeService` that has access to the `ObjectManager` and thus `PublicHolidays`.

`Things`, `Stuff` and `Cosas` all have date/time calculations for the next action required. The date/time calculations need to take in to account the entries in `PublicHolidays` to exclude those dates from the calculation.

`PublicHolidays` can be added, edited and removed after the creation of `Things`, `Stuff` and `Cosas`.

I am using an event system whereby User actions trigger and store an event with related information. Those actions and their information can then be replayed over a base record to produce the current record.

I don't want to inject the `DateTimeService` in to the model. That would be bad. I do however need to be able to access all entries in the `PublicHolidays` table/collection any time an action is triggered to calculate the next applicable date/time.

Some of the time it is not sensible for me to pass all calculated values from a controller to the model or event, as the model may take different subsequent actions based on business logic.

My options as I see them at the moment are:

- Pass more than is required to the model, every time. This seems like a bad idea as I'd need to do business logic in the controller and know all possible outcomes in order to pass all possible date/times to the model.
- Use listeners on the back of the event being applied. This may work, but any subsequent actions will not have the correct data until the listener is triggered (towards the end of the execution)

How can I sensibly access `PublicHolidays` from the `Things`, `Stuff` and `Cosas` models in order that I can calculate dates properly?

Comment: *`Things`, `Stuff` and `Cosas` all have date/time calculations for the next action required.* Doesn't sound good. Could you elaborate why models should care about it?

Comment: A `Thing` has a workflow and depending on the workflow state the next action is required at different intervals. Not all actions change the next action required date/time.

Rather than calculate the values on the fly (iterate through events in reverse, then determine the state of `Thing` at that point in time, then determine offset and calculate) it makes sense for us to store that next action date/time. 

As we use the calculated date/time in search criteria, reporting, etc... it also makes sense for us to store the calculated value. 

Where would you put that if not in the model?

Comment: I'd put this logic to a separate service, e.g. ActionManager which updates models. I see the point to keep next action as a property of the model. I just don't see why model is responsible to calculate it.

Comment: I think perhaps my wording was misleading with "How can I sensibly access `PublicHolidays` from the `Things`, `Stuff` and `Cosas` models".

What I meant was more: How can I, from the model, update the value stored correctly based on `PublicHolidays`?

Comment: I do already have a `DateTimeService` that can calculate, but I don't want to inject the service in to the model. The alternative is an event listener with parameters. This can then access the service.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but if you need to update your models before doctrine events, you need a service to **update** the models. It should use your `DateTimeService` to **calculate** staff and entity manager to access models. The responsibility of the service is to hold relations between your *unrelated* models - something you are trying to put into models themselves, if I get it right. A class relation UML may be quite handy here.